# Lookup tables in Entity Framework 5.0 (Single table for Multiple Lookup Values)

Tags: entity-framework, lookup-tables

In my legacy database we have following way of storing lookup tables.

```
Lookup Table
----------
1 Category 
2 Country 
3 Region
4 Cities
5 Roles
```

Each lookup table record will have multiple Lookup Details

Example:
Inside LookupDetails table, Country will contains all the list of countries, Region will contains all list of region and so on for other values.

Now I am trying to access Categories value inside Product table.

My Product Table is like

- ProductID
- ProductName
- CategoryID

Now CategoryID in Product table refers to LookupDetails value.  Can someone help me to access LookupDetails name (i.e. In my case category name)

I believe EF works smoothly if we have proper relationship among tables.  Since in this case my Product Table is not referenced to Lookupdetails table things are bit complicated, can someone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: What is the primary key of `LookupDetails`?